# Refactor Android NDK make files into modules

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, makefile

I'm having trouble refactoring some make files into manageable modules.

Following is the structure I try to accomplish:

- jni/Android.mk
- jni/Application.mk
- jni/libobj/Android.mk
- jni/libpng/Android.mk
- jni/libzip/Android.mk
- jni/freetype/Android.mk
- jni/ftgles/Android.mk
- jni/qcar/Android.mk
- jni/imagetargets/Android.mk

> Note: I started from the Vuforia SDK ImageTargets example and added
>   some other libraries like reading OBJ, PNG and ZIP files. I've also
>   included the freetype and ftgles library.

I call the other make files from my the root Android.mk file

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS) 

include jni/libobj/Android.mk 
include jni/libpng/Android.mk
include jni/libzip/Android.mk
include jni/freetype/Android.mk
include jni/ftgles/Android.mk
include jni/qcar/Android.mk
include jni/imagetargets/Android.mk
```

You can see **[all make files in a gist on github](https://gist.github.com/niob/5642270)**.

The compiler gives following error:

> Install        : libFTGLES.so => libs/armeabi/libFTGLES.so Compile++
>   arm    : ImageTargets <= ImageTargets.cpp
>   jni/imagetargets/ImageTargets.cpp:44:24: fatal error: libpng/png.h: No
>   such file or directory compilation terminated. make: ***
>   [obj/local/armeabi/objs/ImageTargets/ImageTargets.o] Error 1

Any idea how to make the libpng (and other modules) headers available for the imagetargets module?

Answer (score 1):

I think that specifying the path to the includes in each sub-makefile using `LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES` would ensure that the headers are available when building the final module.

Check the documentation for this flag in the NDK documentation (available in your NDK directory), but from what I understand, it will do exactly what you're trying to do: automatically export the include path of each sub-module to the final module.